# Slick 2.0.2 Error: value === is not a member of Tables.profile.simple.Column[String]

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to start using slick. I have a h2-database and generated classes with scala.slick.model.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator. But when try I try following the examples and query my db using these classes I get scala-errors.

The generated code looks as follows:

```
 /** Entity class storing rows of table User
   *  @param id Database column ID PrimaryKey
   *  @param firstname Database column FIRSTNAME 
   *  @param lastname Database column LASTNAME  */
  case class UserRow(id: String, firstname: Option[String], lastname: Option[String])
  /** GetResult implicit for fetching UserRow objects using plain SQL queries */
  implicit def GetResultUserRow(implicit e0: GR[String], e1: GR[Option[String]]): GR[UserRow] = GR{
    prs => import prs._
    UserRow.tupled((<<[String], <<?[String], <<?[String]))
  }
  /** Table description of table USER. Objects of this class serve as prototypes for rows in queries. */
  class User(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserRow](tag, "USER") {
    def * = (id, firstname, lastname) <> (UserRow.tupled, UserRow.unapply)
    /** Maps whole row to an option. Useful for outer joins. */
    def ? = (id.?, firstname, lastname).shaped.<>({r=>import r._; _1.map(_=> UserRow.tupled((_1.get, _2, _3)))}, (_:Any) =>  throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))

    /** Database column ID PrimaryKey */
    val id: Column[String] = column[String]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
    /** Database column FIRSTNAME  */
    val firstname: Column[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("FIRSTNAME")
    /** Database column LASTNAME  */
    val lastname: Column[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("LASTNAME")
  }
  /** Collection-like TableQuery object for table User */
  lazy val User = new TableQuery(tag => new User(tag))
```

And this is my query:

```
val userResultList = for {
  u <- User if u.id === "foo"
} yield u
```

which results in:

```
Error:(137, 29) value === is not a member of db.Tables.profile.simple.Column[String]
          u <- User if u.id === user.id
                            ^
```

What's wrong?

Comment: have you import the `Implicits`? It could be imported while importing the `XXXDriver.simple._`

Comment: That was it. The import was missing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `slick 2.x`, just import `XXXDriver.simple._` and the compiler will be happy.

For `slick 3.x`, its `XXXDriver.api._`